# connection to ssh server

Tags: ssh, vpn, firewall, android

How to connect to ssh server on port 22 from behind very restrictive firewall  where is only port 80 and 443 available? I tried port mapping on my ssh client but it says it can map local port higher than 1000.

The other problem is I wanted do this connection by my android phone, so I may be limited with necessary software.

I'm not very experienced with VPN but can it be solution?

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options:

1. Run the SSH server on port 80 or 443.
2. Run a [tunnel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) on the SSH server to listen on port 443 or 80 and forward it to 22.
3. Run a VPN on port 80/443.

Essentially, something on the server you're trying to connect to needs to be listening on port 443/80 in order for you to connect to it.

The other solution is to talk to the sysadmin controlling the restrictive firewall and discuss allowing your application/traffic through it if it's business-related stuff!

Comment: But this way I wouldn't be able to run www on my server, am I right? I've already talked to sysadmin, but my request was refused :-( I'm managing dedicated server with virtualization run and I have few ip address available. Could I start something like proxy server for managing the others?

Comment: That's correct, if you have something listening on port 80 or 443 then you can't run a web server on that port.
If you ran a second server that listened on those ports and was inside the same network as your target server, then you could feasibly connect to that as a gateway?